# How to control where your template gets displayed on a page?

Tags: magento-1.9, magento-1.8, layout, template

If I want to display my template file AFTER the "Add to Cart" button on every product view page, but it gets displayed at the bottom of page content?

```
<layout>
    <catalog_product_view>
        <reference name="content">
            <block type="test_example/example" name="product.example" after="product.info.addtocart" template="test/example/view.phtml"/>
        </reference>
    </catalog_product_view>
</layout>
```

I have tried many different `after="product.info.addtocart"` by searching for layout block names in files, but everything gets displayed at the bottom of page content no matter what.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can directly add your template file to `product.info.addtocart` block.

```
<layout>
    <catalog_product_view>
        <reference name="product.info.addtocart">
            <block type="test_example/example" after="-" name="product.example" template="test/example/view.phtml"/>
        </reference>
    </catalog_product_view>
</layout>
```

Answer (score 0):

go to `app/design/frontend/YourPackage/YourTheme/template/catalog/product/view/addtocart.phtml`

and below code after `addtocart` button

```
<?php echo $this->getLayout()->createBlock('test_example/example')->setTemplate('test/example/view.phtml')->toHtml(); ?>
```